# When I click the button of Activity 2, I want to add a container to Activity 1

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm copying code from an Android alarm app.

After setting up the alarm, I want to know how to add a container to the main screen when I press the Save button.

To sum up, my question is:
When you click a button on `Activity2`,
This is how to add a new container to the `Activity1`.

```
savebtn.setOnClickListener {
    var item_view = R.layout.alram_list
    var alram_title = alram_title1
    var alram_time = alram_time
    var al_on = al_on
    var intent1 = Intent(this@AdeDetail, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent1.putExtra("title", title)
    intent1.putExtra("day", t)
    intent1.putExtra("hour", hour)
    intent1.putExtra("min", min)
    startActivity(intent1)   
}
```

This is part of activity code 1.
If the statement keeps false and does not seem to receive the value. I'll be waiting for your help. Thank you.

```
if (intent1.getStringExtra("title") != null){
    Log.d("title","111")
    var title = intent.getStringExtra("title")
    var min = intent.getStringExtra("min")
    var hour = intent.getStringExtra("hour")
    var day = intent.getStringExtra("day")
    var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity)
    var item_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alram_list, null)
    var alram_time = item_view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.alram_time)
    var alram_title = item_view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.alram_title1)
    var alram_on = item_view.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.al_on)
    alram_time.text = day+ "hour:" +"min"
    alram_title.text = title
    alram_on.isChecked =true
    container.addView(item_view)    
}
```

Comment: The current recommended practice would be to use a single Activity with multiple Fragments. The Fragments can share a ViewModel. The first Fragment can observe changes in the actively set alarms via a LiveData in the ViewModel. The second Fragment would post its new alarm to the ViewModel. The set alarm will also need to be persisted to something like SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Let's learn more about Fragmant

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to  write receiving intent in 2nd activity like

var intent = getIntent();

then you can retrive values like

intent.getStringExtra("title")

same for others

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
We should be more careful when deciding the variable name.